# Displaying submenu on left side of page when the horizontal main menu is clicked;show/hide div error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, menu

I have been trying to display a horizontal main menu and on clicking an item in the main menu,a submenu will be displayed vertically on the left side of the page.
This is the master page.

```
<div id="middlebar">
   <ul class="menu">                          
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
     <li id="lnkConfiguration" ><%= Html.ActionLink("Configuration", "Index", "User")%>/li>
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Application Authentication",  "Index",ApplicationAuthentication")%></li>
     <li id="lnkUserAuthentication"><%= Html.ActionLink("User Authentication", "Index",  "UserAuthentication")%></li>
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
  </ul>                   
</div> 
<div>
 <table width="100%">
     <tr valign="middle">
      <td style="width:150px" >
        <div id="divConfiguration" >
           <%Html.RenderPartial("SubMenuConfiguration"); %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" /></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

I am trying to hide the submenu until the main menu is clicked. This is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#divConfiguration").hide();
     $('#lnkConfiguration').click(function() {
     $('#divConfiguration').show(); //.toggle(400);                     
     });
   })                      
 </script>
```

But,what happens is,the submenu appears when the configuration menu is clicked and the page is directing to the controller.Once the page is loaded,the submenu disapperas. This is happening because the script runs again once the page reloads after clicking on the configuration tab. To get around this,I may need to set something that indicates I am on the configuration page so that the submenu is not hidden. But,I do not know where to set the value. Is it in the User Controller Index action?If so, how can I pass the value to the master page click event? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with asp before, so sorry if this is wrong, but this will stop the link from loading and open the div instead. If you need the link to load in order to have the content in the #divConfiguration then i would suggest ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divConfiguration").hide();
    $('#lnkConfiguration').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#divConfiguration').show(); //.toggle(400);                     
    });
});
```

ajax:
Make a page to only display the div configuration after receiving the post variables

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'divconfiguration.asp',
            data: 'page='$(this).attr('href'),
            success: function (msg) {
            $('#divConfiguration ').html(msg).show();
            }
        });
```